# How do I add an existing People Picker Column to a Content Type using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to add an existing People Picker Site Column to an existing Content Type using PowerShell.

I have the following script which fails at attempting to add the field because it is the wrong type

```
$url = "xyz"
$Web = Get-SPWeb $url
AddColumnToContentType "Username" "CTLog"

function AddColumnToContentType($columnname, $contenttypename){
$ContentTypeColl = $Web.ContentTypes
$ContentType = $ContentTypeColl | Where {$_.Name -eq $contenttypename}
If($ContentType -eq $Null)
{
Write-host "Content Type '$ContentTypeName' doesn't exist" -f Yellow
Return
}
$SiteColumnColl = $Web.Fields
$SiteColumn = $SiteColumnColl | Where {$_.Title -eq $columnname}
if($SiteColumn -eq $Null)
{
Write-host "Site Column '$SiteColumnName' doesn't exists!" -f Yellow
Return
}
$FieldCollection = $ContentType.Fields
$Field = $FieldCollection | Where {$_.Title -eq $columnname}
if($Field -ne $Null)
{
Write-host "Site Column '$SiteColumnName' Already Exists in the content type!" -f Yellow
Return
}
$FieldLink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLinkCreationInformation
$FieldLink.Field = $SiteColumn
[Void]$ContentType.FieldLinks.Add($FieldLink)
$ContentType.Update($true)
```

This is the error

**Exception setting "Field": "Cannot convert the "Username" value of type "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUser" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field".**

Advice is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It needed to be Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink not Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLinkCreationInformation

```
$FieldLink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink($SiteColumn)
```